# Exhaustive (brute force) algorithm improvement

Tags: c++, algorithm

I started with the requirements below:

m,n are integers. Search(x,y,z) with

- x+y+z=n
- x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = m

And my code

```
for(int x = 1; x<n; x++)
{
   for(int y = 1; y<n; y++)
   {
      for(int z=1; z<n; z++)
      {
         if((x*x*x + y*y*y + z*z+z*z == m) &&(x+y+z==n))
         {
             cout<<x<<"  "<<y<<"  "<<z;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And BigO = n^3

With the block code above, the algorithm is very slow.  Have you any idea how to boost speed?

Comment: If you switch `if((x*x*x + y*y*y + z*z+z*z == m) &&(x+y+z==n))` to `if((x+y+z==n) && (x*x*x + y*y*y + z*z+z*z == m))` you might not have to compute the set of multiplications

Comment: `z^3 != z*z + z*z`? Am I missing something or is the condition in your code different than the one you wrote?

Comment: z = n-x-y, so x^3+y^3+(n-x-y)^3=m, and so you have to iterate over x and y only.

Comment: Is this underspecified? Are `m` and `n` really integers, or strictly positive and non-zero? Because, if it's the former, `m` and `n` need to cover a much larger range of values.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for the inner loop; given `x` and `y`, you can take `z = n-x-y`. This reduces it to `O(n^2)`.

The second loop only needs to loop while `x+y<n`, since beyond that there's no positive `z` such that `x+y+z==n`. This halves the remaining work.

Once you've done this, there's no need for the second test (since you've already chosen `z` to make that true); fix the typo in the first test and you get

```
for (int x = 1; x<n; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; x+y<n; y++) {
        int z = n-x-y;
        if (x*x*x + y*y*y + z*z*z == m) {
            // found it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also add conditions that `x*x*x < m` and `x*x*x + y*y*y < m` in the two loops.

Comment: In addition, one could calculate `x3 = x*x*x` and the condition `x3 < m` outside the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the internal `for z` loop. Once you have `x` and `y`, you can easily determine `z` as `n-x-y`. This makes it `O(N^2)`.

**UPD**: I think you can even make in `O(N log N)` using binary search approach.

Iterate over `x`. For a given `x`, you need to find such `y` and `z` that `y+z=n-x` and `y^3+z^3=m-x^3`. Assume `n'=n-z` and `m'=m-x^3`.

The problem is symmetric with respect to `y` and `z`, so we can safely assume `y<=z`. This makes `y<=n'/2`.

We need to find such `y` that `y^3+(n'-y)^3=m'`. I am almost sure (though not checked this) that the function `f(y)=y^3+(n'-y)^3` is monotonic on the `[1, n'/2]` interval, so you can use binary search to find the root for `f(y)=m'` equation.

So, for a given `x` you can find needed `y` in `O(log N)` time, which makes `O(N log N)` running time in total.

Comment: `n-z-y` should be `n-x-y`

Answer (score 0):

This one is O(n^2)

```
for(int x = 1; x<n; x++)
{
   int n1 = n - x ;
   for(int y = 1; y<n1; y++)
   {
      int z = n - x - y ;
      if (x*x*x + y*y*y+z*z*z==m)
      {
         cout<<x<<"  "<<y<<"  "<<z;
      }
   }
}
```